# WebSocketSubject как получить ID сессии

Tags: сокет, angular

В своем проекте используем Angular и вместе с ним WebSocketSubject. Возникла необходимость идентифицировать socket, подскажите как из WebSocketSubject получить id сессии на стороне клиента?

Comment: что в твоем понимании "получить id сессии на стороне клиента"? WebSocketSubject это обычный генератор событий, он ни к чему не привязан, в чем проблема отправлять с серверного сокета `client.id`?

Comment: Причина в том что запрос отправляется по http, ответ сервер должен выслать сокеты всем кроме приславшего. Хотелось бы узнать есть ли возможность идентифицировать сокет на клиенте без сервера?